# How to use Crypto++ and return printable byte/char array for RSA?

Tags: c++, cryptography, rsa, crypto++

I'm using the following function to encrypt byte array contain unprintable bytes using RSA. Howeverthis function returns a string value and miss bytes that are not printable.

```
string RSAencrypt(RSA::PublicKey publicKey,string plain) {
    string cipher;

    try {
        AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
        RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor e(publicKey);

        StringSource ss1(plain, true,
            new PK_EncryptorFilter(rng, e,
                new StringSink(cipher)
            ) // PK_EncryptorFilter
        ); // StringSource

    }
    catch (CryptoPP::Exception & e)
    {
        cerr << "Caught Exception..." << endl;
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return cipher;
}
```

How can I return byte array instead?

Comment: I've edited your question to make it more clear. You can roll back or edit your question yourself if I changed it incorrectly (click on "edited" above my name below your question).

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HexEncoder#Encoding_a_Binary_String_.28Filter.29):

```
new HexEncoder(
    new StringSink(encoded)
) // HexEncoder
```

there are also various other encoders listed on the [main page](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/), second row from the bottom. `Base64Encoder` makes most sense.

Of course you need to **decode** again *before* decryption.